# Xamarin Forms - MessagingCenter between two different Pages/Projects

Tags: xamarin.forms, messaging

I'm searching to implement [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/) for X reasons into my Xamarin Forms (Portable Project).

-I have to make communicates the `MainPage.xaml.cs` of the *Project.WinPhone (Windows Phone 8.1)* with the `Pages/MyPersonalPage.xaml.cs` of the *Project* **(PCL Part)**

I think I have to use the both following function:

---

**Send** : `Send<TSender> (TSender sender, string message)`

**Subscribe** : `Subscribe<TSender> (object subscriber, string message, Action<TSender> callback, TSender source = null)`

---

Maybe I misunderstood but, if `<TSender>` is in the *WinPhone* project and `subscriber` is in the *Portable* project, I can't link them about assemblies. (Infinite two ways link)

It means I can't either access `MainPage.xaml.cs` or `Pages/MyPersonalPage.xaml.cs`. **Then, how should I do to make it works?**

My code is already ok otherwise, I'm able to catch the `Events` that I need from the WinPhone part and I'm also able to make the modification I need in the PCL. The only problem is **I need to call this method which makes the modification once the Event comes up**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned *@AlessandroCaliaro* by its **[Answer on Forums Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/206862#Comment_206862)**

In OS side I use something like

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App> ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "OnBeaconServiceConnect");
```

In XF side I use this

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe (this, "OnBeaconServiceConnect", (sender) => {
    // do something
});
```

---

It's says -> **Use something like**

So

**OS side:** `MainPage.xaml.cs` --> It's the **WinPhone8.1 Part Below**, but it should be the same for **others plateforms (Android, iOS, Windows, UWP)**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Project.App>((Project.App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Hi");
```

**XF side:** `ListenerPage.xaml.cs`

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App)Application.Current, "Hi", (sender) => {
    Debug.WriteLine("get hi !!!");
});
```

Thank !

Answer (score 1):

`TSender` can be any class. It describes the event callback's message payload. For example, if you just wanted to send a string to subscribers then you would use `Send<string>()` and `Subscribe<string>()`. Or you can send more complex data structures... like maybe `Send<Person>(newContact, "added")` and `Subscribe<Person>(this, "added", (newContact) => { //... })`.

It is implemented as a `Type` reference so that you can use private classes for `TSender`, which basically means that nobody from outside of the declaring assembly can eavesdrop (private classes are not visible outside of the declaring assembly).

Answer (score -1):

This work perfect !!

(Xamarin Forms Portable Solution)

1. In Android Project:

```
MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Hi");
```

2. In Portable Project (PCL) Any View or Page

```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Hi", (sender) => {
       labelStatus.Text = "We have the Hi message here";
    });
```